# vector::push_back but for an array of elements

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have a vector of ints and a C array containing 9 ints:

```
std::vector<int> storage;
int numbers[9];
```

I am looking for an equivalent to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    storage.push_back(numbers[i]);
```

something like:

```
storage.push_back(numbers, numbers + 8);
```

does this exist? or do I have to make it

---

just to clarify - the vector may already contain useful info in it and I don't want to loose it, just push the array of numbers to the back of it.

Comment: Here's a good [`std::vector` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @JustinRandall things may already be in the vector... I don't want to initialize the vector, just push the contents of an array to the back of the vector

Comment: Yeah use `assign` instead of `push_back` like this `storage.assign(numbers, numbers + 9);`

Comment: I downvoted this question, because the first thing you should do when you want to do something on a type is consult the documentation for that type. That you didn't do that shows a lack of research effort.

Comment: I did research but my understanding of all the terminology is not as strong as yours and its hard to dig through pages of documents

Comment: @JustinRandall `assign` is not what you want to use. It *replaces* the contents of the vector. And comments of that form should actually be answers rather than comments. If you don't think you should answer because the question should be closed or something, don't

Comment: @TheoWalton Pages of documents? cppreference's [page on `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) isn't "pages". Just skim the member functions and see what seems relevant. For example, I know I want to modify the vector to add elements to it, so when I see the section labeled "Modifiers", I'll pay closer attention

Comment: @TheoWalton sorry I'm tired I didn't understand what you wanted.  The vector should be empty, and the result will be equivalent to your array.

Comment: I googled various things like "how to push arrays to vector" and read through a couple of links and a few stackoverflow links also

Comment: @TheoWalton Usually the first place you want to go is reference documentation. I usually type "std::vector" into google and see what comes up. Since I like cppreference, I actually type "cppreference std::vector" to get the page rather than the version on cplusplus.com.

Comment: @Justin Thanks fair enough I'd vote to close because RTFM if I had enough rep.

Comment: @TheoWalton After thinking some more, I'm going to remove my downvote. Even though you didn't do the best research, this question is well-written / well-asked. You clearly put some thought into it and showed exactly what you want. Try to consult documentation first in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so it seems the answer is

```
storage.insert(storage.end(), numbers, numbers + 9);
```

---

Edit: `numbers + 9` is needed and not `numbers + 8` because `vector::insert` does not include the value pointed to by the second iterator!

Comment: As a further note, using raw C arrays is not the nicest, as you have to keep track of the size. However, you could write `storage.insert(storage.end(), std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers));`, although I think you'd have to include the `<iterator>` header